# Xcart - 5.3 disable cache management functionality

Tags: caching, e-commerce, x-cart

Every time I put die or change any file in the project folder I have to manually Login as admin and go to System Tools-> Cache management -> Re-deploy the store and then my changes reflect.

Is there any way to disable this and reflect changes without doing above steps, as project is still in development and i need to check again and again.

Answer (score 3):

I find out a way to disable cache management of xcart 5.x by following below steps:-

- Goto YourProjectDirectory/etc/config.php
- search for "developer_mode" by default it is Off, change its value to "On".